# How to control DraggableScrollableSheet with SingleChildScrollView and reverse

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to use `DraggableScrollableSheet` with `SingleChildScrollView` and set `reverse` for jump of the `TextField`.

But after I set `reverse` to true, `DraggableScrollableSheet` is also reversed, how I can fix this?

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
        minChildSize: 0.73,
        maxChildSize: 0.83,
        initialChildSize: 0.73,
        builder: (context, scroll) => SingleChildScrollView(
              reverse: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              controller: scroll,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ))
```

Comment: This is not possible because the `ScrollController` is shared between the `DraggableScrollableSheet` and the `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: @Mobina i fix this with NotificationListener, if ScrollStartNotification  revers to false